# Getting a patent after a poster abstract got accepted

Tags: publications, patents

I have submitted a poster abstract with my supervisors. The poster abstract got accepted, but we have not presented the poster yet.  The poster describes a method we have invented and now we consider applying for a patent.
Can we still do this? I know this is not possible if we have published the method in an article, but does an accepted poster abstract count as a publication? I'm a PhD student in Europe.

Comment: You have discussed this with your supervisor. Have they or you discussed this with whichever university office is responsible for patents?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have not *yet* made what's called a `public disclosure` of your research, which would render it (from an institutional standpoint) un-patentable. The second you display your poster, or if there is a short paper published along side it, is the second your work becomes `publicly disclosed`. Also bear in mind that if you have, on some website or another, posted code pertaining to the project, etc. this counts as a public disclosure.

As MJeffryes mentioned in his comment, you should talk with the office at your institution responsible for such endeavors (at mine it is called the `research foundation`) as soon as possible. The patent process takes quite some time (re: years; just FYI). Anyway, they should be able to fill you in on all that's necessary and the steps you should take, should you want to pursue that course of action.

**Edit:** As Dan Romik pointed out in the comments, at least in the US, there is a one-year grace period, from when you make a public disclosure, that your work can still be patented-- but anybody could patent it. I found [this](http://www.flhlaw.com/Not-YOur-parents-One-Year-Grace-period-Pre-Application-Invention-Disclosures-under-the-AIA/) helpful in terms of clarifying some of the specifics.  **However**, in speaking with the individual in charge of the `research foundation` at my institution, the impression I got was that, once this public disclosure was made, the foundation was no longer willing to pursue a patent (again, at my particular institution).

Comment: Even after public disclosure, in the U.S. you would have a year to file a patent application. In some other countries public disclosure results in an immediate loss of the right to patent the invention. See: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_disclosure